# Output of a layer with weight argument in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autograd

Is there a way in TensorFlow to compute the output of a layer while specifying the weights, something like `y = layer(x, weights=w)`?

The final purpose is to compute the gradient of some function of the weights, `$w \mapsto layer(x, weights = f(w))$`, however automatic differentiation does not seem to work with `layer.set_weights`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update variables you must you their `.assign` function. See  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable for more details. You can also most definitely pass weights to a layer. You would need to create custom later by subclassing `tf.keras.layers.Layer`. See https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers for more details.